# Flag for grammatical review

Tags: feature-request, flags, grammar

My first language is not English. It is very helpful when there is a native speaking user that improves the English of my question or answer. This makes my question or answer more helpful and it increases the historical value.

My question is: Why isn't there a "flag for grammar review" option? As an interface idea, questions flagged for grammatical review could appear in the same fashion of **first post** and **late post** reviews.

Comment: Do you find that your posts usually don't get corrected? I'd say we're already fairly active without a review queue.

Comment: @Bart I guess you are right, I can't cite a long answer that was not corrected.

Comment: For what it's worth, your English is better than some native speakers'.

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks, it is almost the same, just a bit more general.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's just the whole questions list. :)

Anyone can (and many people do) edit posts to improve grammar and style.